# Update UI (listview) from background service even app closed

Tags: android

I have following scenario

There is listview which have phone call recording data like name, number, call type (incoming/outgoing), recording duration etc.Now i want to upload these recording to dropbox.

Then i started service for uploading recording file to dropbox.I selected 50 recording file from listview with help of Contextual Action bar (CAB) and upload to dropbox with help of this service.

When service is running and uploading file to dropbox at the same time i closed app.I want to in background service should update listview when i closed then app.

I used register receiver and unregister receiver in activity for updating ui. And send broadcast called from service like

Activity - > onCreate - > register receiver - > click on upload button - > start service - > when upload is finished send broadcast-> update ui in activity -> unregister receiver in onPause

This is my current scenario.It is working fine when app is not closed like ui (listview) is in front of me.

But i want when app closed and background service is running, then app ui should be update so that when i opened app all the files are uploaded on dropbox

Please advice.

Comment: Use a cursor adapter for the listview and save all your details in a sqlite table. When a broadcast is received, delete that particular row.

Comment: thats a bit confusing , because if the app is closed , whats the point of refreshing its list view ? the basic logic is that when the app starts it communicates with the service to get its initial state, and as @AshwinSurana said above , this can be achieved either by saving that state in a database or in a text or whatever

Comment: @AshwinSurana You are right now i will store data in database and retrieve from db when app open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table to save all your rows in the listview in to a table. Create a cursor adapter. And use it for your List View. Follow this site for cursor adapter

**Tutorial:** http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

**Reference:**
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html